# Parse nested json using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I try to parse the following json retrieved from a url response. However I am getting error with the getJSONObject(). Any help on parsing this json is appreciated.

```
{
    "results": {
        "5": {
            "files": [
                "http://localhost:8080/files/31_data_cite.png",
                "http://localhost:8080/files/32_sesardm.png"
            ],
            "details": "TEST1",
            "type": "request",
            "date": "2015-10-24 13:02:45.000",
            "user": "abc@yahoo.com"
        },
        "7": {
            "files": [
                "http://localhost:8080/files/31_data_cite.png",
                "http://localhost:8080/files/32_sesardm.png",
                "http://localhost:8080/files/30_mds-db.png"
            ],
            "details": "TEST2",
            "type": "userexperience",
            "date": "2015-10-24 13:07:32.000",
            "user": "s@yhoo.com"
        }
    }
}



    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
       if (xhr.status == 200) {
        var  arr= JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        //var str = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText, null, 2);
                   //alert(str);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);

 for (var key in obj.results) {
              var values = obj.results[key];
              
              for (var v in values) { //v - files, details
               
               if(v=="files")
               {
                var files = values.files;
                for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) { 
                 document.write(" "+ files[i]);
                }
               }
                document.write( " "+values.details+" "+values.type+" "values.user +"<br>");

              }
             
           
          }
    }
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler just to get the results directly from the parsed object. `mainObj = arr.results;`

Comment: Yes, wouldn't arr.result OR arr["results"] get you the data you are trying to put into your mainObj variable?

Comment: Getjsonobject appears to be a Java function. If you want the data from results just do arr.results

Comment: From where did you get `getJSONObject`?

Comment: what error you got ?

Comment: ok i used obj.results to read child elements. But i cannot access the values of "files"..

Comment: Do you mean help parsing it, or help accessing properties within it?You can use an accessor such as `obj.results['7'].files`.

Comment: The "files" has multiple values. I cannot access them as follows: var values = obj.results[key];
for(var i = 0; i< values.files.length; i++) {
var obj = values.files[i];
document.write("FILES: " + obj);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            // var str = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText, null, 2);
            for ( var key in obj.results) {
                document.write("Key: " + key + "<br>");
                var values = obj.results[key];
                if (typeof values === 'object') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < values.files.length; i++){
                        document.write("FILES: " + values.files[i]
                                + "<br>");
                    }
                }
                document.write("DATA: " + values.details + " "
                        + values.type + " " + values.user + "<br>");
            }
```